# Can't restore the database

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongorestore

I dump the mongodb database using `mongodump --db dbName`. Now when on different system I tried to restore it using mongorestore it is showing me error:

> Failed: mindcentral.user: error creating collection mindcentral.user: error running create command: BSON field 'OperationSessionInfo.create' is a duplicate field

My dump folder is on desktop, so I am using command

```
mongorestore --db DBName Desktop/dump/DBName
```

Comment: This is hard to tell, without seeing an excerpt of the dump, esp. concerning `OperationSessionInfo`. Could you add that? Also, what are the versions of MongoDB on both systems?

Answer (score 0):

You just Follow:
 Mongorestore:
 Syntax:

```
mongorestore -d databasename databasepath.
```

Example:

```
mongorestore -d user ./Desktop/dump/user
```

where the user is a database name.